# Spring Integration - Request/Reply messaging using JMS and gateway

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a problem using SpringIntegration 2.2.1: i would like to exchange messages between two different systems using JMS (WMQ as broker), implementing Request/Reply pattern (as synchronus messaging) in JBoss AS 7.

---

My xml configuration files contain:

**1)** outbound configuration:

```
<bean id="BOHAdjustmentConverter" class="com.test.interoperabilitytracking.internal.BOHAdjustmentConverter" />

<si:publish-subscribe-channel id="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" task-executor="integrationTaskExecutor" />
<si:publish-subscribe-channel id="outboundBOHAdjustmentErrorChannel" task-executor="integrationTaskExecutor" />

<si:gateway id="outboundAspectGateway" service-interface="com.test.interoperabilityframework.service.RequestGateway"
    default-request-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" 
    default-reply-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannelEnriched" 
    error-channel="interoperabilityError"
    default-reply-timeout="20000" />

<!-- INTEROPERABILITY FRAMEWORK GATEWAY -->
<bean id="outboundBOHAdjustmentAspectBean" class="com.test.interoperabilityframework.service.impl.OutboundAspect">
    <property name="requestGateway" ref="outboundAspectGateway" />
    <property name="outboundEnrichedErrorChannel" ref="interoperabilityError" />
    <property name="defaultChannelTimeout" value="1000" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="outboundBOHAdjustmentAspect" ref="outboundBOHAdjustmentAspectBean">
        <aop:pointcut id="theExecutionOfCreateUpdateBOHAdjustmentMethod"
            expression="execution(* com.test.interoperabilitytracking.internal.*AdjustmentBOHOutboundImpl.notifyCreateBOHAdjustment(..))" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="theExecutionOfCreateUpdateBOHAdjustmentMethod" method="sendReceiveAndReturnWithGateway" />
        <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="theExecutionOfCreateUpdateBOHAdjustmentMethod" throwing="error" method="handleError" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<si:header-enricher input-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" output-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnriched">
    <si:header name="direction" value="outbound" />
    <si:header name="directionType" value="request" />
    <si:header name="entityName" value="BOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="entityFQN" value="createupdatebohadjustment.api.interoperabilitysample.tsf.BOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="domainName" value="Inventory" />
    <si:header name="apiID" value="BOHAdjustment.C.O.R" />
    <si:header name="apiVersion" value="1.0" />
    <si:header name="operationName" value="createBOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="sourceApplication" value="VPS" />
    <si:header name="targetApplication" value="HOST" />
    <si:error-channel ref="interoperabilityError" />
</si:header-enricher>

<si:header-enricher input-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentErrorChannel" output-channel="interoperabilityError">
    <si:header name="direction" value="outbound" />
    <si:header name="directionType" value="request" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entityName" value="BOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="domainName" value="Inventory" />
    <si:header name="apiID" value="BOHAdjustment.C.O.R" />
    <si:header name="apiVersion" value="1.0" />
    <si:header name="operationName" value="createBOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="sourceApplication" value="VPS" />
    <si:header name="targetApplication" value="HOST" />
    <si:error-channel ref="interoperabilityError" />
</si:header-enricher>

<si:channel id="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannelMapMessage">
    <si:interceptors>
        <si:wire-tap channel="interoperabilityResult" /> <!-- TODO this is a temporary solution because if the adapter fails to sent the message we don't trace it -->
    </si:interceptors>
</si:channel>

<si:chain input-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnriched" output-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannelMapMessage">
    <si:transformer ref="dozerMapper" method="convert" />
    <si:service-activator ref="mapMessageBuilderCreateupdatebohadjustmentOutbound" />
</si:chain>

<!-- ***** reply channel used by outbound gateway ***** -->
<si:channel id="outboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannelEnriched">
    <si:interceptors>
        <si:wire-tap channel="interoperabilityResult" />
    </si:interceptors>
</si:channel>

<si:channel id="requestResponseReplyChannel" />

<si-jms:outbound-gateway id="requestReplyOutboundGateway" 
    request-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannelMapMessage"
    connection-factory="leoEcoSystemConnectionFactory" 
    reply-channel="requestResponseReplyChannel" 
    request-destination-name="outboundBOHAdjustmentRequestDestination"
    reply-destination-name="outboundBOHAdjustmentReplyDestination"
    extract-reply-payload="true"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" receive-timeout="10000">
</si-jms:outbound-gateway>

<!-- outbound reply header enricher -->
<si:header-enricher input-channel="requestResponseReplyChannel" output-channel="outboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannelEnriched">
    <si:header name="direction" value="outbound" />
    <si:header name="directionType" value="reply" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entityName" value="BOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="domainName" value="Inventory" />
    <si:header name="apiID" value="BOHAdjustment.C.O.R" />
    <si:header name="apiVersion" value="1.0" />
    <si:header name="operationName" value="createBOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="sourceApplication" value="VPS" />
    <si:header name="targetApplication" value="HOST" />
    <si:error-channel ref="interoperabilityError" />
</si:header-enricher>


<bean id="channelBridgeHandlerBOHAdjustment.C.O.R" class="com.test.interoperabilityframework.service.impl.ChannelBridgeHandler">
    <property name="channel" ref="outboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" />
</bean>
```

**2)** My inbound configuration file contains:

```
<bean id="inboundBOHAdjustmentContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="leoEcoSystemConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="outboundBOHAdjustmentDestination" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="3-7" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="interoperabilityErrorHandler" />
</bean>

<si:header-enricher input-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" output-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnriched">
    <si:header name="boundPayload" expression="payload" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="direction" value="inbound" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="directionType" value="request" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entityName" value="BOHAdjustment" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entityFQN" value="com.test.interoperabilitytracking.internal.BOHAdjustementVO" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="domainName" value="Automat" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entity" overwrite="true" expression="payload.get('BOHAdjustment')" />
    <si:header name="serviceContext" overwrite="true" expression="payload.get('ServiceContext')" />
    <si:header name="operationName" value="createUpdateBOHAdjustment" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="sourceApplication" value="LEO" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="targetApplication" value="AA" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="apiID" value="BOHAdjustment.C.I.R" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="apiVersion" value="2.0" overwrite="false" />
    <si:error-channel ref="interoperabilityError" />
</si:header-enricher>

<si:channel id="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" />

<si:channel id="inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannel" />

<si:channel id="inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannelEnriched">
    <si:interceptors>
        <si:wire-tap channel="interoperabilityResult" />
    </si:interceptors>
</si:channel>

<si-jms:inbound-gateway id="inboundBOHAdjustementGateway" acknowledge="auto" 
    container="inboundBOHAdjustmentContainer"
    request-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannel" 
    reply-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannel"
    request-destination-name="inboundBOHAdjustementRequestDestination"
    extract-reply-payload="true"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" />

<!-- inbound reply header enricher -->
<si:header-enricher input-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannel" output-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannelEnriched">
    <si:header name="direction" value="inbound" />
    <si:header name="directionType" value="reply" overwrite="true" />
    <si:header name="entityName" value="BOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="domainName" value="Inventory" />
    <si:header name="apiID" value="BOHAdjustment.C.O.R" />
    <si:header name="apiVersion" value="1.0" />
    <si:header name="operationName" value="createBOHAdjustment" />
    <si:header name="sourceApplication" value="VPS" />
    <si:header name="targetApplication" value="HOST" />
    <si:error-channel ref="interoperabilityError" />
</si:header-enricher>

<si:channel id="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnsureTracking">
    <si:interceptors>
        <si:wire-tap channel="interoperabilityResult" />
    </si:interceptors>
</si:channel>

<si:chain input-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnriched" output-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnsureTracking">
    <si:service-activator ref="payloadHandler" method="getEntity" />
    <si:transformer ref="jaxbProviderInbound" method="unmarshal" />
    <si:transformer ref="dozerMapper" method="convert" />
    <si:service-activator ref="integrationLoginUtil" />
</si:chain>

<si:service-activator input-channel="inboundBOHAdjustmentChannelEnsureTracking" output-channel="interoperabilityResult" ref="service"
    method="createUpdateBOHAdjustment" />
```

**3)** I have omitted some other beans like converter and jaxb provider. 
The connectionFactory is a JNDI name on a queue configured into JBoss AS 7 `standalone.xml`, an instance of JMS `ConnectionFactory` implemented by WMQ.

**4)** I have other configuration files and others classes to perform the tracking.

I would like to realize:

- when a service is invoked, starts an aspect and the gateway send a message and wait for a response;
- on the channel there is an henricher and some others service activator. At this point, i would persist a record on DB to track the `direction` = "outbound" and `directionType` = "request";
- the message arrives to the queue;
- an inbound gateway on the other system, de-queue a message and applies to the message its logic. On this channel there is the header enricher. Here i would track `direction` = "inbound"  and `directionType` = "request";
- a reply message (also the same message) is sent to another channel with an header enricher. At this point i would like to persist `direction` =  "inbound" and  `directionType` = "reply";
- The reply message arrives to outbound gateway. On this channel i have another header enricher, i would persist as `direction` = "outbound" and `directionType` = "reply";

**PROBLEM** 
the problem is that the reply does not work nor in ountbound than in inbound. Spring Integration doc explains that to perform this scenario, both outbound and inbound must be request/reply and suggest to use `outbount-gateway` and `inbound-gateway` with reply channel because they are bidirectional. Unluckily, i don't understand why it not work correctly, the servlet is blocked on a reply and when i try to convert the Spring Message, i never receive "reply" value for `directionType`.

Comment: There should be no issue with what you describe, but you don't show anything sending the reply to `inboundBOHAdjustmentReplyChannel`; I presume you omitted that. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow on both sides; all should become clear.

Comment: I had already used the DEBUG mode, and i had noted that "reply" value for `directionType` attribute wasn't never received. I think that one of `request-destination-name` or `reply-destination-name` could be incorrectly.